# shell script to check ping packet loss & avg latency on AIX

Tags: shell, scripting, ping

I'm trying to create script which will ping to remote server and displays only 
1)  % packet loss
2) average round trip latency in ms

for packet loss i created line

```
`ping -c 3 -s 14 x.x.x.x|grep packet|awk '{print $7}'|cut -d'%' -f1`
```

which only gives packet loss,

my problem starts when ip is not reachable output of line changes 
and hence i'm not able to capture both

for reference i'm showing output of both scenarios

```
   `/pefmephbir >ping -c 3 -s 14 10.9.50.225`
  PING 10.9.50.225 (10.9.50.225): 14 data bytes

  --- 10.9.50.225 ping statistics ---
  **3 packets transmitted, 0 packets received, 100% packet loss**


  `/pefmephbir >ping -c 3 -s 14 10.9.50.220`
  PING 10.9.50.220 (10.9.50.220): 14 data bytes
  22 bytes from 10.9.50.220: icmp_seq=0 ttl=63 time=0 ms
  22 bytes from 10.9.50.220: icmp_seq=1 ttl=63 time=0 ms
  22 bytes from 10.9.50.220: icmp_seq=2 ttl=63 time=0 ms

  --- 10.9.50.220 ping statistics ---
  **3 packets transmitted, 3 packets received, 0% packet loss
  round-trip min/avg/max = 0/0/0 ms**
```

hope someone with expertise in scripting can help me out

TIA

Comment: Does the first instace not have a line like `round-trip min/avg/max = 0/0/0 ms**`?

Comment: You don't need `grep`, `awk` and `cut`. `awk` will do the whole lot for you. Start with `awk '/loss/ || /trip/ {...}'`

Comment: hi konsolebox no 1st instance don't give  round-trip min/avg/max = 0/0/0 ms line

Comment: hi mark got syntax when run ping -c 3 -s 14 x.x.x.x| awk '/loss/ || /trip/ {...}'

Comment: @tnt5273 You should show expected output format.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
ping ... | awk '/packet loss/{x="Loss:" $7} /round-trip/{x="Trip:" $4} END{print x}'
```

If it sees a line with "packet loss" in it, it creates a string `x` with the packet loss percentage. If it sees a line with "round-trip" it overwrites the string `x` with the round trip time. At the end, it prints whatever the string `x` is set to.

In the light of your comments...

```
awk '/packet loss/ && /100/{x="Loss: " $7} /round-trip/{split($4,a,/\//);x="Ave: " a[2]} END{print x}'
```

So, now the "packet loss" line must also contain "100" before we pick it up. And the 4th field of the "round-trip" line is split into an array `a[]` using `/` as separator, then we take the second element of `a[]` as the average and store that in our output string `x`.

Comment: hi mark i'm close to my requirement is it possible i show only round-trip avg value  and only loss when 100% loss ? TIA

Comment: Have another look - hopefully we are getting closer :-)

Comment: hi mark getting syntax error surly getting closer :) well round-trip will not come if packet loss is 100% :)

Comment: Sorry, I slipped an excess comma in there. Try again please.

Comment: Thx mark you did it, time to party you are invited :)

Answer (score 2):

Using sed:

```
ping ... | sed -n -e 's/.*\(100% packet loss\).*/\1/p' \
                  -e 's_.*min/avg/max = [0-9]*/\([0-9]*\)/[0-9]*.*_\1_p'
```